synchronous execution in a tokio::spawn
I spawned a new thread with tokio::spawn and some asynchronous tasks. Like so:
#[tauri::command]
pub async fn player_prepare(
    app: tauri::AppHandle,
    user_id: i32,
    audio_file_id: String,
) -> Result<AudioFileResponse, ErrorResponse> {
    let response = match player::prepare(audio_file_id).await {
        Ok(response) => response,
        Err(e) => {
            error!("Failed to get response: {:?}", e);
            return Err(ErrorResponse::Error {
                error_code: ErrorCode::NetworkError,
                message: ErrorCode::NetworkError.message(None).to_string(),
            });
        }
    };
    match &response.audio_file.results {
        Some(results) => {
            if results.is_empty() {
                warn!("Results are empty.");
                return Err(ErrorResponse::Error {
                    error_code: ErrorCode::NoResults,
                    message: ErrorCode::NoResults.message(None).to_string(),
                });
            }
            // Save the audio_file as a json file.
            // These operations should not be blocking.
            save_audio_file(&response.audio_file);
            prepare_result_files(
                app,
                &user_id.to_string(),
                response.audio_file.id,
                results.to_vec(),
            );
            Ok(response)
        }
        None => {
            warn!("No results found.");
            return Err(ErrorResponse::Error {
                error_code: ErrorCode::NoResults,
                message: ErrorCode::NoResults.message(None).to_string(),
            });
        }
    }
}

fn prepare_result_files(app: tauri::AppHandle, audio_file_id: i32, results: Vec<ResultFile>) {
    debug!("Preparing result files: {:?}", audio_file_id);
    let id = audio_file_id.to_string();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        save_result_files(&id, &results).await;
        download_result_files(&id, results).await;
        prepare_tracks();
        prepare_players(&id).await;
        let _ = app.emit_all(PLAYER_IS_READY, audio_file_id);
    });
}

The problem is that the emil_all event sometimes gets executed before all the await tasks are finished. I want to perform the functions inside the spawn synchronously so that the code emits PLAYER_IS_READY event correctly. I have looked at the spawn_blocking one, but I don't think that's what I need.
Any pointers?

This is impossible. .await performs the operations one-after-another. The bug must be in other code you didn't show us, and so we cannot solve it.

Seems like emit_all is called somewhere else before

@ChayimFriedman, when you say it's impossible, you mean that the tasks inside async move {} is always executed asynchronously? Or you mean that the order of the execution is up to tokio as the async runtime?

Anyway, I updated the code.

The task is executed asynchronously, but the statements inside it are executed synchronously (relative to each other).

This is still isn't a Minimal Reproducible Example (which you should post), but perhaps player_prepare() is called twice, and the first time's emit_all() is executed before the second time's preparations are complete?

@ChayimFriedman ok, you're probably correct here about the player_prepare() is called twice.
